# Automatical creation of nuget package from existing project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

We are using Visual Studio 2010, we develop ASP.NET MVC applications.

Our deploy process includes manually building a nuget package on the UI and uploading it.

We need to figure out how to create a nuget package from code including adding the files, adding properties, adding the changelog as description.

Is there a solution to achieve this goal?

Thanks

EDIT:

After a lot of painful work, not knowing what is the goal and how can I achieve the goal I've come up with the following code:

```
NuGet Update -self
nuget spec -f
mkdir bin
mkdir Scripts
mkdir Styles
copy ..\TestProj\TestProj\bin bin
copy ..\TestProj\TestProj\Scripts Scripts
copy ..\TestProj\TestProj\Styles Styles
copy ..\TestProj\TestProj.sln
```

I'm not sure the NuGet operations are correct and I'm not sure at all the files should be migrated into a package this way, as I'm new to NuGet. I would be very grateful if somebody would show me the right direction about:

- how should I add files
- how should I add properties
- how should I add changelog as description

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the solution was the following:

```
cd C:\myfolder
mkdir content
mkdir Styles
del content /F /S /Q /A
del Styles /F /S /Q /A
copy C:\myotherfolder\Scripts Content
copy C:\myotherfolder\Styles Styles
NuGet Update -self
NuGet pack mypackage.nuspec
```

Note that mypackage.nuspec already existed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the [Nuget spec and Pack command](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference) ? It would help you to easily create a package out of a csproj or any set of files following the the [nuget folder convention](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package).
Let us know if you have any further questions around it.

Comment: I'm currently checking that document, but I'm not familiar with nuget. I was asked to create a proof-of-concept, a project from scratch with file copying, property definition and a changelog for description. I've created a new project, I have upgraded nuget to its newest version, so everything is prepared, but I'm stuck, as I don't know how should I solve the file copying, property definition and changelog problem with a set of nuget commands from code. The specification of the task is bad, as I'm not aware of what's being done manually and how, but I still have to try.